# Two horizontal lines with Mega Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm using well known Mega Drop Down Menu plugin [from here](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/). 
It is working fine but not if you want to make two lines of menu. I create an example here : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJGFW/5) There is a problem on second line menu is too height when you hover on it.   Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not positive if this menu was designed to be used in this manner but you could do something like:

```
$('#mega-menu-1').dcMegaMenu({
    rowItems: '3',
    speed: 0,
    effect: 'slide',
    event: 'hover',
    fullWidth: true,
    beforeOpen: function() {
        $(this).find(".mega").css("top", 40 + $(this).offset().top-$(this).parent().offset().top);
    }
});
```

Basically to change the menu top `beforeOpen` depending on the offset of the menu item selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/r0m4n/HJGFW/10/